# Java out of bounds error in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am a student and this is my second ever app but I don't know why I get an error that array is out of bounds. I have attached the code as well as the error screenshot, if anyone is able to help me please do.

It should return the details of the genre stored in the genre column but its giving me an error

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    AsyncHttpClient client;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    Workbook workbook;
    List<String> titles,genre,imgUrl;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String url = "https://github.com/AmeyaGawde326/Ani_Recommend/blob/main/AnimeList.xls?raw=true";

        TextView titleView = findViewById(R.id.titleView);
        TextView descView = findViewById(R.id.descView);
        Button Recommended = findViewById(R.id.buttonR);
        ImageView Cover = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        titles = new ArrayList<>();
        genre = new ArrayList<>();
        imgUrl = new ArrayList<>();

        client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        client.get(url, new FileAsyncHttpResponseHandler(this) {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, File file) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Download of Data Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, File file) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Database Downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    WorkbookSettings ws = new WorkbookSettings();
                    ws.setGCDisabled(true);
                    if(file != null){
                        try {
                            workbook = workbook.getWorkbook(file);
                            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
                            for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getRows(); i++) {
                                Cell[] row = sheet.getRow(i);
                                titles.add(row[0].getContents());
                                genre.add(row[8].getContents());
                                imgUrl.add(row[1].getContents());
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (BiffException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }
            }
        });


        Recommended.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Generating a random number which is less than no of rows
                Random random = new Random();
                Sheet sheet_no = workbook.getSheet(0);
                int index = random.nextInt(sheet_no.getRows());
                //getting the values of the no of row it generated
                String Title, Genres, ImageUrl;
                Title = titles.get(index);
                Genres = genre.get(index);
                ImageUrl =imgUrl.get(index);
                titleView.setText(Title);
                descView.setText(Genres);
                //Using Picasso to download the image
                Picasso.get().load(ImageUrl).into(Cover);

            }
        });

    }


}
```

The first app I wrote with a smaller Excel file works

The Excel file has 9 columns so it should work with index 8 and display anything that's in that column I don't know why this error shows up:

[image: The error]

Comment: Why not use `row.length - 1` for the last element? Also you should check what `row.length` actually is by logging it

Comment: Using row.length-1 solved it

Answer (score 0):

You set the `index` to 8 but the `ArrayList` only provide 7 items in `length`. This means it expect one more to come, that isn't loaded.

```
genre.add(row[8].getContents());
```

Another indication is this:

```
Genres = genre.get(index);
```

You hardcoded the amount of rows, but the content depends on what is getting loaded. If it doesn't get the exact number it crashes.